# Show all facebook friends when sending an app request using Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, list, facebook-app-requests

I can send app request to my friends, it is working, the problem is that I can't see the full list of my friends. I see only 12 entries.

How can I see all of my friends?

```
    private void inviteFacebookFriends(FragmentActivity activity)
    {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", getString(R.string.check_out_this_app));

        OnCompleteListener onCompleteListener = new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error)
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        // "Request cancelled!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // "An error occurred!";
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    String reqId = values.getString("request");

                    if (reqId != null)
                    {
                        // "Success sent request !";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // "Request cancelled !";
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(activity, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(onCompleteListener)
        .build()
        .show();
    }
```

However I can search for my friends, but I want to see all of them.
Should I implement my own listview?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I also want to see the full list but am stuck without a solution. Any help please.